# Cordova / Phonegap geolocation from GPS, Network and Wifi

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, geolocation

So I started this app using Cordova and integrated Google Maps with API V3. When using geolocation like so :

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccessLoc, onErrorLoc, { maximumAge: 3000, enableHighAccuracy: true });

I get the position with the help of the GPS. Therefore I need to be outside. If I stay inside it won't lock, I could wait forever. But when removing options and calling simply like this :
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccessLoc, onErrorLoc);

Then it locates me with the help of wifi and network, but no GPS.

I would like to get both, just like native apps do !

Thanks ahead for any help !

Comment: try bumping up `maximumAge` to 10000 and and set `enableHighAccuracy` to false. Three seconds isn't long enough for indoor GPS and I believe high accuracy is what is disabling wifi and network location.

Comment: Hey and thanks, but if I do that GPS won't launch at all, the enableHighAccuracy is what says to use the GPS if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So upgrading to Cordova 3.4.0 seems to have fixed the issue ! Try this if you run into the same problem.

Comment: I've upgraded to 3.4.0, still having the issue :(

Comment: Sorry to hear this man, I am able to use geolocation nicely since upgraded... Your manifest file has the required lines ? Also, don't use the Geolocation plugin Cordova provides, if you installed it on your project uninstall it, the native HTML5 geolocation is better.

Comment: It definitely has the right lines, if I got rid of them it says "Cannot start Geolocation Service", when I add them back in - I either get a timeout (if I include the timeout option) or else nothing happens at all, if I enable high accuracy I get the little GPS Icon - but nothing happens

Comment: I've uninstalled and tested - same thing. Reinstalled, same thing :(

Answer (score 1):

What if you created a fallback method so if the highAccuracy check doesn't take it calls the wifi/network method. Something like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccessLoc, onErrorLoc, { maximumAge: 3000, enableHighAccuracy: true });

function onErrorLoc() {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccessLoc, onErrorFinal);
}
```

This would allow for the watching method to continue to run, but if no location is found using that method it would call a one time position check using the looser location method.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer !

onErrorLoc is defined with an alert, it never triggers.

But I just upgraded to Cordova 3.4, and it looks like it works ! Apparently they fixed the issue !

Thanks again :)